# How to get a date from a string and remove lines older than specific date

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm working on a script to find missing Kafka topics in a folder. I'm quite far already, but I just need one more step to make it perfect. The script searches through multiple folders and files and returns below result.

```
2022 Mar 11  ADR00180 - Is missing the topic for:  xx
2022 Jul 17  ADR00195 - Is missing the topic for:  xx
2022 Feb 16  ESO00011 - Is missing the topic for:  xx
2022 Aug 09  EMF00023 - Is missing the topic for:  xx
2022 May 24  ESO00012 - Is missing the topic for:  xx
2022 May 22  ESO00013 - Is missing the topic for:  xx
```

Now I'm trying to convert the date in the string to a 'real' date and remove the lines older than one week. I am though unsure where to start.

Comment: You should be able to do that with the find command?

Comment: please update the question with a) definition of `'real' date`, b) sample string (that contains a date?), c) the code you've tried (and the wrong results generated by said code) and d) the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter it through this (g)awk script:

```
BEGIN {
    lastweek = systime() - 60*60*24*7;
}

{
    "date +%s -d \""$1" "$3" "$2"\"" | getline linedate;
    if (linedate > lastweek)
        print;
}
```